# Border tab doesnt expand when content box is split in two

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a page with Bootstrap. I splitted the box of the tab content into 2x pieces. Now when I do that, the border around the tabs box doesn't expand with it. It does when I remove the split of the content.

Here's my code :). Lines 168 is where I have splitted. Thanks!

```css
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 21%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.container-fluid {
 padding:0px auto;
 padding-left:0px;
 margin:0px auto;
}
.col-xs-4{
 width:21%;
}
.col-xs-8{
 width:79%;
}
.input-group{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.col-xs-6margin.col-xs-6{
 margin-top:50px; 
}
.btn-label {position: relative;left: -12px;display: inline-block;padding: 6px 12px;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;}
.btn-labeled {padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;}
.btn { 
 margin-bottom:10px;  
 }
.tabs.col-xs-8{
 float:right;
 margin-left:20px;
}

/* Tabs panel */
.tabbable-panel {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

/* Default mode */
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #737373;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a > i, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open .dropdown-menu, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active > a > i {
  color: #404040;
}
.tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.portlet .tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Below tabs mode */

.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #f3565d;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .tab-content {
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive Navigation Menu - Bootsnipp.com</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid"><!--Full page container start-->
 <div class="row"><!--First row start navmenu and main content-->

<!--Start of Left panel Navigation bar-->
                
        <div class="col-xs-4"><!--Left navpanel start-->
   <div class="nav-side-menu"><!--Left panel content start-->
    <div class="brand">Nova Computers
                </div><!--End brand div-->
                 <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
                     <div class="menu-list">
                         <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
                             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Customers <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products"> 
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Add Customer</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                                      <li>New Service 1</li>
                                      <li>New Service 2</li>
                                      <li>New Service 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> New <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
                                      <li>New New 1</li>
                                      <li>New New 2</li>
                                      <li>New New 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li>
                                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Customers</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
      </div><!--End menulist div-->
            </div><!--End nav-side-menu div-->
  </div><!--Left navpanel End -->
          
<!--End of Left panel Navigation bar-->
<!--Start of Main content box-->        
        <div class="col-xs-8"><!--begin content box right-->
         <div class="row"><!--begin first row content box-->
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6margin"><!--Start 50% of content box left-->
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Business Name</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Salutation</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Firstname</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Middle</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>  
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Lastname</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Zipcode</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Housenumber</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Street</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
    </div><!--End 50% of content box left-->
                
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6margin"><!--Start 50% of content box right-->
                 <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Place</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                       <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 1</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 2</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 3</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 4</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                </div><!--End 50% of content box right-->
            </div><!--End of first row-->
            
            <div class="row"><!--Begin second row main content-->
             <div class="col-xs-12 tabs"><!--Full width container tabs start -->
                 <div class="tabbable-panel"><!--tabbable-panel start-->
                     <div class="tabbable-line"><!--tabbale-line start-->
                         <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                             <li class="active"><a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">Extra info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                             <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1"><!--panel tab 1 start -->
                                 <div class="col-xs-6"><!--colum split start-->
                                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Place</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                       </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 1</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 2</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 3</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 4</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--colum split stop-->
                                    <div class="col-xs-6"><!--colum split start--> <!--here's my problem-->
                                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Place</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                       </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 1</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 2</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 3</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 4</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--colum split stop-->
                                 </div><!--panel tab 1 stop-->
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2"><!--panel tab 2 start-->
                                 <p>testteststest</p><!--this works perfectly-->
                                    <p>testteststest</p>
                                    <p>testteststest</p>
                                    <p>testteststest</p>
                                </div><!--panel tab 2 stop-->
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3"><!--panel tab 3 start-->
                                </div><!--panel tab 3 stop-->
                            </div><!--tab content stop-->        
                        </div><!--tabbale-line stop-->
                   </div><!--tabbable-panel stop-->
                   
                   <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:0px;"><!--Start buttons-->                     
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                        <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                        <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>Cancel</button>
                   </div><!--End buttons-->
             </div><!--end Full witdh container row 2-->
            </div><!--End second row main content-->
  </div><!--End content box right-->
<!--End of Main content box-->          
 </div><!--end main row-->        
</div><!--Full page container end -->         
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a MINIMAL example? No one likes having to look through hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: what for did you publish bootstrap code here?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your col-xs-6 in a row like this. And also check the bootstrap documantation for grids

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

```css
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 21%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.container-fluid {
 padding:0px auto;
 padding-left:0px;
 margin:0px auto;
}
.col-xs-4{
 width:21%;
}
.col-xs-8{
 width:79%;
}
.input-group{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.col-xs-6margin.col-xs-6{
 margin-top:50px; 
}
.btn-label {position: relative;left: -12px;display: inline-block;padding: 6px 12px;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;}
.btn-labeled {padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;}
.btn { 
 margin-bottom:10px;  
 }
.tabs.col-xs-8{
 float:right;
 margin-left:20px;
}

/* Tabs panel */
.tabbable-panel {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

/* Default mode */
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #737373;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open > a > i, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a > i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.open .dropdown-menu, .tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.active > a > i {
  color: #404040;
}
.tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.portlet .tabbable-line > .tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Below tabs mode */

.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #f3565d;
}
.tabbable-line.tabs-below > .tab-content {
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive Navigation Menu - Bootsnipp.com</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid"><!--Full page container start-->
 <div class="row"><!--First row start navmenu and main content-->

<!--Start of Left panel Navigation bar-->
                
        <div class="col-xs-4"><!--Left navpanel start-->
   <div class="nav-side-menu"><!--Left panel content start-->
    <div class="brand">Nova Computers
                </div><!--End brand div-->
                 <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
                     <div class="menu-list">
                         <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
                             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Customers <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products"> 
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Add Customer</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                                      <li>New Service 1</li>
                                      <li>New Service 2</li>
                                      <li>New Service 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> New <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
                                      <li>New New 1</li>
                                      <li>New New 2</li>
                                      <li>New New 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li>
                                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Customers</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
      </div><!--End menulist div-->
            </div><!--End nav-side-menu div-->
  </div><!--Left navpanel End -->
          
<!--End of Left panel Navigation bar-->
<!--Start of Main content box-->        
        <div class="col-xs-8"><!--begin content box right-->
         <div class="row"><!--begin first row content box-->
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6margin"><!--Start 50% of content box left-->
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Business Name</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Salutation</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Firstname</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Middle</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>  
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Lastname</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Zipcode</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Housenumber</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Street</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
    </div><!--End 50% of content box left-->
                
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6margin"><!--Start 50% of content box right-->
                 <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Place</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                       <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 1</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 2</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 3</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 4</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                </div><!--End 50% of content box right-->
            </div><!--End of first row-->
            
            <div class="row"><!--Begin second row main content-->
             <div class="col-xs-12 tabs"><!--Full width container tabs start -->
                 <div class="tabbable-panel"><!--tabbable-panel start-->
                     <div class="tabbable-line"><!--tabbale-line start-->
                         <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                             <li class="active"><a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">Extra info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                             <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1"><!--panel tab 1 start --><div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-xs-6"><!--colum split start-->
                                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Place</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                       </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 1</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 2</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 3</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 4</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--colum split stop-->
                                    <div class="col-xs-6"><!--colum split start--> <!--here's my problem-->
                                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Place</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                       </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 1</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 2</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 3</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Phone 4</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div><!--colum split stop-->
                                 </div><!--panel tab 1 stop-->
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2"><!--panel tab 2 start-->
                                 <p>testteststest</p><!--this works perfectly-->
                                    <p>testteststest</p>
                                    <p>testteststest</p>
                                    <p>testteststest</p>
                                </div><!--panel tab 2 stop-->
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3"><!--panel tab 3 start-->
                                </div><!--panel tab 3 stop-->
                            </div><!--tab content stop-->        
                        </div><!--tabbale-line stop-->
                   </div><!--tabbable-panel stop-->
                   
                   <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:0px;"><!--Start buttons-->                     
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                        <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                        <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>Cancel</button>
                   </div><!--End buttons-->
             </div><!--end Full witdh container row 2-->
            </div><!--End second row main content-->
  </div><!--End content box right-->
<!--End of Main content box-->          
 </div><!--end main row-->        
</div><!--Full page container end -->         
</body>
</html>
```